# WSO2 REST API to capture invalid/valid xml request in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: xml, wso2, rest, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1.I have designed Rest API which received xml payload as request.In this if request is valid i can able to print incoming request payload by using log mediator, often if request is wrong, unfortunately can't able to get exact request that sent into my system.

Getting below exception when receives invalid xml request.

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
```

I need to capture the input request that sent by client whether it is valid or not. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

**API Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/WSO2API" name="WSO2API" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="API Logger"
                    value="====Inside QRSag_NAC Lead Creation API Process Started====" />
                <property name="===Input Request Logger===" expression="$body" />
            </log>
            <log level="full" />
            <payloadFactory media-type="json" description="Form Response Payload">
                <format>{"StatusCode":"$1","Message":"$2"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="200" />
                    <arg value="Success" />
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="custom">
            <property name="==Response==" expression="json-eval($.)"></property>
            </log>
            <property name="HTTP_SC" value="400" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
                description="HTTPStatusCode" />
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"
                type="STRING" description="HttpMessageType" />
            <respond />
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence />
        <faultSequence>
            <log level="custom" separator=",**, " description="FaultSequence">
                <property name="=====Faulty Response=====" value="Inside default Fault Sequence" />
                <property name="=====message=====" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" />

            </log>

            <payloadFactory media-type="json" description="Form Response Payload">
                <format>{"StatusCode":"$1","Message":"$2"}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="400" />
                    <arg value="Failure" />
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="HTTP_SC" value="400" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
                description="HTTPStatusCode" />
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"
                type="STRING" description="HttpMessageType" />
                <log level="custom">
            <property name="==Response==" expression="json-eval($.)"></property>
            </log>
            <respond />
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Valid Request:**

```
<leaddetails>
    <customer>
        <extdburn>0</extdburn>
        <title/>
        <forename>Jared</forename>
        <surname>Parker</surname>
        <mobile>0406008974</mobile>
        <email>Jwparke888@hotmail.com</email>
    </customer>
    
</leaddetails>
```

**Invalid request:**

```
<leaddetails>
    <customer>
        <extdburn>0</extdburn>
        <title/>
        <forename>**Jared & Justin**</forename>
        <surname>Parker</surname>
        <mobile>0406008000</mobile>
        <email>Jwparke888@hotmail.com</email>
    </customer>
    
</leaddetails>
```

**Logs:**

```
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,003] []  INFO - LogMediator API Logger = ====Inside QRSag_NAC Lead Creation API Process Started====, ===Input Request Logger=== = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="h
ttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,004] [] ERROR - LogMediator Could not build full log message: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:554)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:988)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getFullLogMessage(LogMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:138)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:326)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:372)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseFullName(StreamScanner.java:1924)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseEntityName(StreamScanner.java:2050)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveNonCharEntity(StreamScanner.java:1479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2788)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 39 more
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,015] [] ERROR - WSO2API Could not build full log message: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:554)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:230)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:125)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:113)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:988)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getFullLogMessage(LogMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:138)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:326)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:372)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseFullName(StreamScanner.java:1924)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseEntityName(StreamScanner.java:2050)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveNonCharEntity(StreamScanner.java:1479)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2788)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1072)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 39 more
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,036] []  INFO - LogMediator =====Faulty Response===== = Inside default Fault Sequence,**, =====message===== = Could not build full log message: com.ctc.wstx.exc
.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,037] []  INFO - LogMediator ==Response== = {"StatusCode":"400","Message":"Failure"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Salute! I had a similar problem, perhaps replacing the symbols '**' with Unicode one will help you. You can find codes you need for example [1]: https://unicode-table.com/

Comment: Hi @Andrey Guzik,
Thanks for ur suggestion, issue is i am passing & in request. as Niitha suggested, i need to replace & with &amp; in request, but request sent by client.. my problem here is i can't get request sent by client in log. if i get this input request, then only i can able to replace. right?

Answer (score 0):

With the above API configurations and with the invalid request payload, this issue can be easily reproducible with WSO2 EI 6.1.1.

```
[2021-03-05 17:27:54,004] [] ERROR - LogMediator Could not build full log message: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?) 
    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [6,26]
```

The above error has been thrown when WSO2 EI is trying to build the message payload inside a full log mediator. The issue is happening because of the '&' character in your invalid request payload. This is a special character and WSO2 EI cannot handle special characters like these and hence it will throw an exception.

If you really want to use the '&' character in your request payload you need to use escape characters (&amp;) to avoid breaking the flow.

Comment: Hi @Nikitha Udeshana,
Thanks for ur reply. yes you are correct, need to make changes in request, above invalid request formed by myself for unit testing purpose, since request sent by client, in this case, how can i get that invalid request in my log or else i need to approach client to send the valid request?

Comment: Hi @Justin,
According to the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax), the ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form and should be escaped. Therefore, the best way to handle this is to ask the client to send a valid request.

However, this issue only appears when the message payload gets built inside the EI server. Therefore, you can enable [wire logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs) to check the message payload without using Full log mediators.